# waiting for user input on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-input

I am currently making an agenda which should be controlled via a seperate input form.

On this form I need to wait for user input before I can move the next input field.

Below is the entry for the to do field for adding a task.
After that it also has fields for date, time and reminders.

```
private void btn_Say_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = tbx_Say.Text;

    if(text.Contains("Add") || text.Contains("add"))
    {
       if(text.Contains("Task") || text.Contains("task"))
       {
            screen.btn_Tasks.PerformClick();
            while(screen.task.tb_TaskToDo.Text == "")
            {
                tbx_Anne.Text = "What should happen?";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the perform click starts up a new which needs to be filled through the input form.
with or without the Thread.Sleep(1000) this form will not fully show and it waits for user input which I can not give...

Comment: Your while loop locks the ui. If you want to monitor something us a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Use ShowDialog() instead of Show()

Comment: hmmm -1, I think users need to ask more info before they think people don't do research and stuff...

Comment: @SebastiaanHaverkate: I'm guessing the downvote is because it's very unclear from the question what your UI looks like and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time I've solved my problem, tested it and it works.

```
    private void btn_Say_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = tbx_Say.Text;
        tbx_Say.Text = "";
        if (status == 0)
        {
            if (text.Contains("Add") || text.Contains("add"))
            {
                if (text.Contains("Task") || text.Contains("task"))
                {
                    screen.btn_Tasks.PerformClick();
                    tbx_Anne.Text = "What should happen?";
                    status = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (status == 1) // to do
        {
            if (text != "")
            {
                screen.task.tb_TaskToDo.Text = text;
                tbx_Anne.Text = "On which date?";
                status = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (status == 2) // date
        {
            DateTime date;
            if(DateTime.TryParse(text, new CultureInfo("nl-NL"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                screen.task.dateTimePickerTask.Value = date;
                tbx_Anne.Text = "And what time?";
                status = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                tbx_Anne.Text = "Please nter date as dd-mm-yyyy.";
            }
        }
        else if (status == 3) // time
        {
            int h;
            int m;
            if(text.Length == 5 && Int32.TryParse(text.Substring(0,2), out h) && text[2] == ':' && Int32.TryParse(text.Substring(3), out m))
            {
                screen.task.tb_TimeTask.Text = text;
                tbx_Anne.Text = "Do you want to add reminders?";
                status = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                tbx_Anne.Text = "Please insert time as hh:mm.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks very much like the wrong way to be doing this. I would suggest

1. Create a form that pops up with a disabled OK button and an enabled Cancel button
2. Make all the controls bar the first one disabled.
3. Add an event on the text changing, on the first text box to enable the next control (doing appropriate validation).
4. Repeat step 3 for all of your controls.

Do not introduce Thread.Sleep in your UI code, this will cause the form to lock up and stop responding.

Comment: as I only have one input field, I only have 1 control, thus this does not work.

And yes it must stay 1 input field due to the fact this simulates a program it needs to be connected with in the future.

Comment: @SebastiaanHaverkate: That just confuses me more, can you post a screenshot of your dialog and the steps you expect the user to take? It may make more sense then and I may be able to suggest something else to help.

Comment: The idea is that it will be voice controlled through a virtual assistant (VA). Therefore you have just 1 in- (what you say to your VA) and 1 output field (what your VA says to you). the agenda might be visible, but with voice control you can not directly control it. The VA takes you through every field of f.e. a task to add, change or delete it.

Comment: but I already found a solution that works. (can make it an answer tomorrow) but something more efficient is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use chained select statements to do this instead of taking input from users you can give them options to select from drop down menu and according to selected options you can provide further form here ia a tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery/

Comment: sorry my bad but still u can use chained selects instead of taking input from user